# How do I print webpages to PDF on Big Sur?

Tags: pdf, printing

I can't find any way to do this for free.

Is there any free virtual printer for Big Sur so that I can print webpages (from chrome/firefox) to pdf?

I learned about cups-pdf and pdfwriter but homebrew doesn't seem to support cups-pdf and pdfwriter is old, doesn't work.

Any pointer will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ⌘P on the webpage and select save to PDF. This should work for chrome and safari as well. [image: The Firefox Print dialog]

Comment: Note this works in pretty much any app, anywhere in macOS. It's built-in at system level ever since OSX began. If you click the down arrow there are other useful options too.

Comment: @Tetsujin Note that Chrome and Firefox don't use the system print dialog by default (although it's accessible from "Print using system dialog..."), so the option to print to PDF might appear in a different location depending on the app.

Comment: I went through this with someone on another stack yesterday. I even dug out Firefox & Chrome to test it. Yup. Chrome, as always, ignores the Mac Toolbox guidelines (idk why they insist on doing that) Pretty much everything else, inc Firefox, uses the standard Mac Toolbox dialog, with the options bottom left.

Comment: Homebrew's 'lack of support' for CUPS-PDF should not be a barrier. CUPS-PDF can be installed individually, without reference to homebrew.